# Sort values into separate columns in large datasets

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, sorting

I have a very large dataset with transactional data, where customerID and purchase items are not sorted into columns. I want to sort all the products/ purchase items into separate columns and indicate whether the customer bought or not with a binomial marker, e.g. 1 if customer bought and 0 if they didn't. How can I do this without dragging down "1s" in separate columns?

It looks like this **https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data/data**

Comment: please post some sample data to help us understanding your issue

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to insert columns..

Comment: You can format your data as table e.g. [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) than just insert it in your question and format as code (CTRL+K)

Comment: could you please specify what Database you are using as source Access or SQL. Also specify the Sort order & the Key field to sort. As you have written,"I want to sort all the products/ purchase items into separate columns" , means you want sorted data to copy to other place ? Better post sample data.

Comment: I can't figure out how to paste my table without getting the formatting distorted. Also the dataset is really large. But it looks like this one from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data/data

Comment: I am not using a database, just Excel. Would this be easier to do if I used a database like Access? If we look at this very similar dataset, I'd like the items in the third columns/ descriptions to be sorted into separate columns according to the type of item it is.

Comment: Anne, it's still not very clear what you want to do.  Are you saying you want to add a separate column for each unique item in column C (Description), using the name of the item as the column heading, and then, indicate with 1's and 0's which customers bought each item?

Comment: If that's correct, it raises many more questions.  How many unique items are there?  Will that number grow? What do you want to do with the information in the other columns, qty, date, price, etc?

Comment: You could take a screenshot of your data, upload it to a sharing site (eg Imgur.com) and **edit your question** to include the link to the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I was not allowed to add screen shot. I want to take the different items that are listed chronologically in one column and give them their own separate columns. Then I want to give them binary or boolean values based on whether the customerID bought it or not. So if customer 003 in column A bought items listed in column B and C, both cell B3 and C3 would get a 1 or a TRUE. If 003 only bought item in column B, but not in column C, B3 would be 1 or TRUE and C3 would be 0 or FALSE. Sorry I wasn't more clear before.

Comment: So yes, I guess I have a twostep problem: 1) separate items into their own columns, and 2) give them binary or boolean values that can be understood by a statistics program. There are about 14 different product categories which each will get a column.